# reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I'm receiving an error message when I run my app in Xcode (terminating app due to uncaught exception). Below I pasted the error message and what I believe is the part of the code that's creating the problem. I'm new and just learning objective c so please be easy with me. Thank you!

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])); Thread 1:signal SIGABRT
    }
}
```

- **The Error Message:**

  2014-11-25 10:07:19.794 SamplePhotoReDo[81276:108898068] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3318.16.14/UITableView.m:6116
  2014-11-25 10:07:19.798 SamplePhotoReDo[81276:108898068] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier AllPhotosCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
  *** First throw call stack:'

**The script that I believe is causing the error:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    NSString *localizedTitle = nil;

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:AllPhotosReuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        localizedTitle = NSLocalizedString(@"All Photos", @"");
    } else {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CollectionCellReuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        PHFetchResult *fetchResult = self.collectionsFetchResults[indexPath.section - 1];
        PHCollection *collection = fetchResult[indexPath.row];
        localizedTitle = collection.localizedTitle;
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = localizedTitle;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: The key is this: 'must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'. This means you have to tell Xcode what cell belongs to which cell identifier. You can do this in code or in Interface Builder.

Comment: Disregard,  think I found the problem

Comment: Thank you dasdom for your quick response but I think I resolved the problem.  In the storyboard changed the Table View content from dynamic to static..  That fixed the first error message but now I have another error message:   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Comment: You try to excess an object at the index 2 in an array which is empty. Add a break point at 'All Exceptions' and reproduce the crash.

Comment: Thank you again for your help dasdom.. As I mentioned earlier, Im new to objective c so sorry for this stupid question but is the script below part of the NSArray thats causing the problem? Im not sure how to add a break point..

 - (NSArray *)assetsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths
{
    if (indexPaths.count == 0) { return nil; }
    
    NSMutableArray *assets = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:indexPaths.count];
    for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in indexPaths) {
        PHAsset *asset = self.assetsFetchResults[indexPath.item];
        [assets addObject:asset];
    }
    return assets;
}

Comment: Correction: I think I know how to add a break point I just don't know where to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

in ViewDidLoad add:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:AllPhotosReuseIdentifier];
```